# SharePoint 2010: How to hardcode web part ID in AllUsersWebPart XML?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a feature which provisions a custom **Default.aspx** file to my **publishing site**.

In the **elements.xml**, I have various **AllUsersWebPart** nodes which populate the zones with web parts. I need to supply a hardcoded ID (guid) to each of these web parts at this point -- does anyone know how to do this?

I know that the format of a webpart ID is **g_00000000_0000_0000_0000_000000000000**, but if I add an ID property (see below) and then activate my feature, the guids of the webparts are all different.

```
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="TopZone" WebPartOrder="1">
<![CDATA[
    <webParts>
        <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
            <metaData>
                <type name="..." />
                <importErrorMessage>...</importErrorMessage>
            </metaData>
            <data>
                <properties>
                    <property name="ID" type="string">g_FB777184_F9AB_4747_AA71_1BF0C96E535A</property>
                </properties>
            </data>
        </webPart>
    </webParts>
]]>
</AllUsersWebPart>
```

FYI: I need to hardcode an ID for each of my web parts because I have a seperate feature receiver which uses the ID to locate each web part on the page (I have 6x identical parts on the page with the same title) and then it assigns an audience to each part (so that only 1 is visible at any given time to a user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good and bad news...

The approach I was using is in fact valid, however it will only work if your web parts are **not** placed in a web part zone. If placed in a zone, the web part infrastructure automatically sets the WebPart.ID value (confirmed on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.id.aspx)).

In order to hard-code the web part IDs, you need to place your web parts directly in the page layout (so that you can place them in directly within the page's markup).

Personally, I have opted to leave the web parts in the zones and instead use unique titles which I can use later in my feature reciever to identify the parts.

Answer (score 3):

You were so close.  Try using the "ID" attribute of the "AllUsersWebPart" element (or if provisioning a List View Web Part using the "View" element):

```
<View List="Lists/Announcements" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Top" ID="g_42fa735b_3cae_47d2_a773_b591b9abfd7a" />
```

or

```
  <AllUsersWebPart ID="g_21f871c5_3575_4182_a7e2_64f682877071" WebPartOrder="1" WebPartZoneID="Top">
    <![CDATA[
    <webParts>
      <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
          <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
          <properties>
            <property name="ListUrl" type="string">Lists/Tasks</property>
            <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
          </properties>
        </data>
      </webPart>
    </webParts>
    ]]>
  </AllUsersWebPart>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Completely alternative solution to your original problem, not really an answer to the question):*

Why don't you use the SPWebPartManager (from within the Feature Receiver) to grab the web parts from the page, and set your properties that way?

I'm assuming the 6x identical ones will be in the same zone, placed one after another, so you could just iterate through the WebParts in the manager class where the the parts belong in a particular Zone.

Comment: Thanks for your comments James. You're absolutely on the right track, except there's just one or two gotcha's... 

Because my feature is activated as part of the site definition, I need to use the SPLimitedWebPartManager in my feature receiver -- and this doesn't contain any zone info. So, I'm currently iterating through each web part in the page and checking against the web part title, although I was hoping to make my 6x audience targeted parts all have the same tiel, e.g. "News" as apposed to "News - Audience Name 1" etc. This is why I was looking to use IDs to differentiate between them.